# What are some tips on killing the giant fish boss, "Del Lago"?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

The [Del Lago](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Del_Lago) is a very fast and sneaky boss. The main problem is the terrain. You are stuck inside a boat, in the middle of a lake, with nothing but harpoons.

How do you overcome this obstacle?

Comment: It has been a while since I played the game, but there is actually a "1 hit kill" method. That's how I beat it the first time round. Pretty sure it is an RPG chest that becomes reachable just before the fight. I remember it is on a small island by itself, and I think it is marked on the map by a sunken ship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no magic involved here. Try to avoid the obstacles when he pulls you, try to hit him with the harpoons at the same time, by aiming a little higher. When he seems to have disappeared and you auto switch to aiming mode, wait for the signal about his location and shoot as much as you can. Aim a little lower to be sure to hit him.

Comment: Avoiding obstacles is a main issue, as there is little control over the boat.

Comment: True, the boat isn't as responsive as wanted. The way I used is that, when a obstacle shows up, go as much as you can in the opposite direction. Being pulled by Del Lago will put you back in the right direction soon after.

Comment: When he dives under and charges at you open-mouthed, he is hard to dodge.

Comment: You have to land enough blows in his mouth to not be thrown into the water